# ruby net/telnet sent only first half of the strings

Tags: ruby, telnet

i need to send about 30 commands to remote device by telnet, for test automation. Commands written to a file in a form:

```
command1
command2
command3
...
```

Then I use the script, only first half of commands sent from the file. If in the file was 10 strings, then only firts 5 sent. If in the file was 20 strings, then only first 10 sent. Of course I can just add extra lines, but I do not like this solution.

```
require 'net/telnet'

host = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "192.168.1.111",
                        "Output_log" => "log")

host.login("Name" => "admin",
           "Password" => "admin")

File.open("filename").each {|line| host.cmd line}

host.close
```

Comment: I don't know how, but `chomp` fix this problem.

Comment: Consider submitting your revised code as an answer in case anyone else needs to solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аdding `chomp` solved the problem.

```
File.open("filename").each {|line| host.cmd line.chomp}
```